# Django migrate broken, won't forget a deleted column

Tags: python, django, django-models

Using django 1.7.5, I made changes to User_Profile by adding a field:

```
school = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank=True, default="")
```

Then,

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

No problem. It added the field. Next,

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

gives me:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: mathbreakers_userprofile__new.school may not be NULL
```

Uh oh. Well, after trying different things by making the field `default=""` or `blank=True`, nothing works. Forget it, I deleted the field and reverted the model to the way it was when everything worked fine. Model looks like it did before, and I run makemigrations, it removes the field (it says). Great!

However,

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

still results in the SAME error, complaining about the field I added and then deleted.  It's as if I can't make django forget that that field exists. But it doesn't exist in my models.py file. How do I fix this? Where is that field? Is it in my SqlLite that I should go in and delete it manually from there?

NOTE: I have manually deleted broken migration files and also reverted to a previous GIT version before the changes. Nothing has worked, `python manage.py migrate` seems to still be broken..

Comment: did you already have that field before and then change it?

Answer (score 3):

Although I am not using South (I think), the following solved my issue:

[Backwards migration with Django South](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814190/backwards-migration-with-django-south)

Specifically, I followed these steps:

- Remove the culprit field from models.py
- Delete the culprit migration files AND their .pyc counterparts
- Rolled back migration to the number just before the error, e.g.

$ python manage.py migrate MY_APP_NAME 0024

> Running migrations:
>
> No migrations to apply.

Although the last step seemed to do nothing, now when I run makemigrations and migrate, everything is fine with zero errors.

Comment: Nice answer, didn't think about backwards migration.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: try editing the latest migrations .py file in app/migrations.

I just had a similar problem myself (Django 1.8.6, Postgresql). I wanted to create a subclass of an existing class, and wanted to move a field from the base class to the subclass. I had (I thought) deleted the offending field from the parent class, but when I ran `python manage.py migrate`, I was getting was getting an error message saying the field in the subclass was clashing a field of similar name in the base class.

I looked at the last migrations .py file (in app/migrations), and noticed that the command to remove the field from the base class were *after* the command to create the subclass. So I edited the migrations file (changed the order of commands), and `python manage.py migrate` ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by following these simple steps:

1. Delete all python generated migrations in `migrations` folder.
2. clear all data in `django_migrations` table manually.

And everything should work.